# How to fix the logic of my "Blackjack Player Simulator"?

Tags: python

I am currently working on a Blackjack player simulator in python in which the user walks through the steps of a game. I have had some success with the structure of the program, but face errors with my logic when trying to work through the process that should be triggered when an ace is drawn. For example, often times when an ace is drawn, the "New Total" text repeats itself once. Another problem with the program is the two totals that are used when an ace is drawn do not carry to the next card draws/totals as I would hope. Being new to programming, I apologize in advance for the potential of this description sounding vague as I have trouble recognizing the errors in depth.

All help is appreciated.

```
import random

def play_hand_dealer():
    total = 0
    player_is_bust = False
    ace_was_thrown = False
    another_card = True
    ace_total = 0
    high_ace = 10

    while player_is_bust == False and another_card != "n":
        card = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10])
        total = total + int(card)

        if card == 1:
            ace_was_thrown = True
            ace_total = high_ace + int(total)
            print("Ace     New Total is", total, "or", ace_total, end = "   ")

        if ace_total < 21 and ace_was_thrown:
            ace_total = total + 10
            print("New Total is ", total, "or", ace_total, end = "    ")

        else:
            print(card, "New Total is ", total, end = "    ")

        if total > 21:
                player_is_bust = True

        if total < 21:
            another_card = input("Another Card? ")

    if ace_was_thrown:
        if  total + 10 >= 17 and total + 10 <= 21:
            total = total + 10

    if player_is_bust:
        print("Bust")

    else:
        print("        Final Total:",total)


choice = ""
while(choice != "q"):
    play_hand_dealer()
    print()
    choice = input("Enter to play again , or 'q' to quit: ")
    print()
```

Comment: Perhaps this question, as it is, is more suitable to Code Review.SE. Try to isolate your issues into more specific programming questions.

Comment: @iled As long as there are "logic errors", it doesn't belong to Code Review at all. Please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely Thank you, that was helpful. I've seen other cases where questions like this were advised to go to CR, but that topic make it much more clear. Thanks. Anyway, I still think the OP should break down this question in smaller and more specific ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know rules of blackjack, so I can only comment on the code itself, not the game logic.

```
total = total + int(card)
ace_total = high_ace + int(total)
```

You don't need int() in those, since these are already a numbers.

---

```
    if card == 1:
        ace_was_thrown = True
        ace_total = high_ace + int(total)
        print("Ace     New Total is", total, "or", ace_total, end = "   ")

    if ace_total < 21 and ace_was_thrown:
        ace_total = total + 10
        print("New Total is ", total, "or", ace_total, end = "    ")

    else:
        print(card, "New Total is ", total, end = "    ")
```

You probably should replace it with if, elif, else. This is why you are getting "New Total" twice. Or you can move all your print below the if if else, it depends on what you need to do.

---

```
    if total > 21:
            player_is_bust = True

    if total < 21:
        another_card = input("Another Card? ")
```

This place doesn't know what to do if total == 21. You probably should change it to this:

```
if total > 21:
        player_is_bust = True

elif total < 21:
    another_card = input("Another Card? ")

else:
    break
```

---

It's possible to get more than one ace in one game, I hope your program handles this correctly.

Please explain the rules of this game if you need a bit better help.

Comment: Thank you! You have no idea how helpful this was to me.